# Launching a simulator fails with an error: No template

Tags: xcode, xcrun

I am running the following command to launch iOS simulator via Xcode

```
 xcrun instruments -w 2E755803-3DFD-4722-B6B7-25498BCFF551
```

and it fails with

```
Instruments Usage Error : No template (-t) specified
instruments, version 7.2 (59503)
usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]
```

so what is that template that is required here?

Answer (score 1):

I got around it by launching a different device first then the one i wanted.

Comment: Same here.  Moved from `iphone 5s` to `iphone 6` and things worked